# Bizarre precedence and associativity

Tags: haskell

Looking through operator associativity and precedence I found the following:

```
infixr 0 $
infixl 1 &
infixl 4 <$>
infixl 1 <&>
```

This seems bizarre. `&` and `<&>` have the same precedence, but `$` and `<$>` not only have widely different precedence, but also associate in different directions.

Is there any good reason for this, or is this just an historical wart? If it's an historical wart, how would you go about changing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming the `<&>` you're talking about is from the lens package. In that case, the lens operators are really set up to get along with the other lens operators, and they don't really worry so much about the regular operators, so `<&>` and `&` are probably a coincidence. The other two, however, are more thought out.

`$` is the lowest precedence, by definition. That is why it exists; to change the order of text so drastically that it can reduce the need for parentheses quite a bit. So it's naturally set at 0. Meanwhile, `<$>` is an application inside a context, something that you actually need to do, as opposed to `$` which is just syntax help. So `<$>` is of a higher precedence to get along with other operators like it, for example the Alternative class operator `<|>` is at a lower precedence so that those calls can be chained with `<$>` appropriately.

As for the associativity, that's simply in how the operators are used. `$` is often used for simpler function composition. One might write `f $ g $ x` to mean `f (g x)`. Whereas `<$>` is almost always chained with `<*>`, which is also `infixl 4`. That way, statements like the following are valid.

```
(+) <$> [1, 2, 3] <*> [10, 20, 30]
```

That expression will parse as the following, due to the left associativity.

```
((+) <$> [1, 2, 3]) <*> [10, 20, 30]
```

Which is exactly what we want. The function (+) is curried and accepts two parameters which should be passed in one-by-one. With right associativity, the following would occur.

```
(+) <$> ([1, 2, 3] <*> [10, 20, 30])
```

This says to apply all of the numbers in the first list to the numbers in the second list and then add the result to... something. Needless to say, that would not typecheck.